# Get-SqlErrorLog Email Backup Failure

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a PowerShell script where I want to have it email me when a backup for SQL Server fails.  I am trying to use Get-SqlErrorLog.  The Script works, but no email sent.  Here is the script:

```
$event = Get-SQLErrorLog -ServerInstance $env:COMPUTERNAME -Since Yesterday  | Where-Object { $_.Text -match 'failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE' }
    
    if ($event.EntryType -eq "Error")
    {
        $PCName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        $EmailBody = $event | format-list -property * | out-string
        $EmailFrom = "$PCName me@mycompany.org"
        $EmailTo = "me@mycompany.org" 
        $EmailSubject = "SQL Server Backup failure for $env:COMPUTERNAME"
        $SMTPServer = "smtp.org"
        Write-host "Sending Email"
    
    Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer smtp.org -To me@mycompany.org -From me@mycompany.org -Subject "SQL Server Backup Failure for $env:COMPUTERNAME" -Body $EmailBody
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "No error found"
        write-host "Here is the log entry that was inspected:"
        $event
    }
```

Comment: `$event` is an array of records so `if ($event.EntryType -eq "Error")` probably isn't doing what you're expecting.

Comment: Modified it and now works..